# Using Gimp script in windows command line Error

Tags: windows, cmd, gimp, script-fu

I try using this script to convert .PSD with using a certain script.

This is my code:

```
@echo off

set gimp="c:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\gimp-console-2.8.exe"

%gimp% -i -b '(flatten-layer-groups 1 test.psd)' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

but he does not work, with this error:

```
(gimp-console-2.8.exe:1336): LibGimpBase-WARNING **: gimp-console-2.8.exe: gimp_
wire_read(): error
GIMP-╬°шсър: ═хтючьюцэю юЄъЁ√Є№ 'c:\Work\Test\1': No such file or directory

GIMP-╬°шсър: ═хтючьюцэю юЄъЁ√Є№ 'c:\Work\Test\test.psd)'': No such file or direc
tory

GIMP-╬°шсър: ═хтючьюцэю юЄъЁ√Є№ 'c:\Work\Test\0)'': No such file or directory
```

Please Help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use double qoutes, something like

> %gimp% -i -b "(flatten-layer-groups 1 \"test.psd\")" -b "(gimp-quit
>   0)"

See [this link](http://chris.widdowson.id.au/?p=842#)

Answer (score 0):

For example xd function opens c.jpeg which is on desktop on Windows 10 for Gimp version 2.10

`gimp-2.10 -b "(xd \"C:\\Users\\YourUsername\\Desktop\\c.jpeg\")"`